# Understanding about render :partial in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I change the content status on my application, background of database update works fine. But the `link_to :loading` operation is not working.

View : _feedback_question_status.html.erb for an element in page

```
<% if feedback_question.status == 1 %>
    <span id="feedback_question">enabled -- <%= link_to "change", {:action=>"feedback_question_status",:status => 0,:feedback_question=>feedback_question.id}, :remote=>true, :loading => "$('#feedback_question_disable_#{feedback_question.id}').replaceWith('<p>Loading..</p>')", :update =>"feedback_question"%></span>
<% else %>
    <span id="feedback_question">disabled -- <%= link_to "change",{:action=>"feedback_question_status",:status => 1, :feedback_question=>feedback_question.id }, :remote=>true, :loading => "$('#feedback_question_enable_#{feedback_question.id}').replaceWith('<p>Loading..</p>')", :update =>"feedback_question"%></span>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

has the `update_attributes` and `render :partial=>'feedback_question_status'`

And
on the Server:

```
Started GET "feedback/feedback_question_status?feedback_question=6&status=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-27 16:25:47 +0530
... Snippet
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
...
   (30.7ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered _feedback_question_status.html.erb (2.7ms)
```

the last line shows the partial was renderd. but no changes on the views.  It means there nothing happen to the element on the page.

rake routs for feedback_question:

```
  feedback_feedback_question_status        /feedback/feedback_question_status(.:format)                       feedback#feedback_question_status
                 feedback_questions        feedback/new_feedback_question(.:format)                          feedback#new_feedback_question
             edit_feedback_question        /feedback/:id/edit_feedback_question(.:format)                     feedback#edit_feedback_question
           update_feedback_question        /update_feedback_question/:id(.:format)                            feedback#update_feedback_question
           feedback_question_status        /feedback_question_status(.:format)                                feedback#feedback_question_status
```

after refresh the page it shows the changes. but i don't want to load the page again.

Comment: Please show us `bundle exec rake routes | grep feedback_question`

Comment: You are writing in rails 3 using programming style of rails 2.   Consider using named routes, and converting all of the javascript to UJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't passed the local variable "feedback_question" from controller to partial file  _feedback_question_status.html.erb.

So you need to pass local variable "feedback_question" like below

render :partial => "feedback_question_status", :localts => { :feedback_question => @feedback_question }

where @feedback_question is a instance variable needs to be created in your controller.

Comment: yes. i have created and passed the locals with the `render :partial`.

Comment: Create action_name.js.erb, within this js.erb file you just use like below,

$("#cert_elements").html("<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => "cert_elements/element",
                                                         :locals => { :cert_element => @cert_element } )) %>");

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this

```
<% if feedback_question.status == 1 %>
  <span id="feedback_question">enabled -- <%= link_to "change", {:action=>"feedback_question_status",:status => 0,:feedback_question=>feedback_question.id}, :remote=>true, :loading => "$('#feedback_question_disable_#{feedback_question.id}').replaceWith('<p>Loading..</p>')", :update =>"feedback_question"%></span>
<% else %>
  <span id="feedback_question">disabled -- <%= link_to "change",{:action=>"feedback_question_status",:status => 1, :feedback_question=>feedback_question.id }, :remote=>true, :loading => "$('#feedback_question_enable_#{feedback_question.id}').replaceWith('<p>Loading..</p>')", :update =>"feedback_question"%></span>
<% end %>
```

By this

```
<span id="feedback_question"><%= feedback_question.status == 1 ? "enabled" : "disabled" %> -- <%= link_to "change", {:action=>"feedback_question_status",:status => (feedback_question.status == 1 ? 0 : 1),:feedback_question=>feedback_question.id}, :remote=>true, :loading => "$('#feedback_question_disable_#{feedback_question.id}').replaceWith('<p>Loading..</p>')", :update =>"feedback_question"%></span>
```

Don't repeat your code.